# How do I clear recycler view items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I working on application were i have used recycler view to show data from firebase. When user gets logout the items in recycler view doesn't destroy.when some other user login he/she can see previous user data.

How do i clear recycler view when user press logout button.I tried to clear all data from app but it closes the app and user needs to reclick the app.

my adapter class.

```
public class UserHistoryViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserHistoryViewAdapter.UserHistoryViewHolder>{
private List<UserHistoryModel> userHistoryModels;
private Dialog UserHistoryPopUp;
private TextView bookingid_pop_up,check_in_date_time_pop_up,room_no, floor_no ,room_type;
private Button close_btn;


public void setUserHistoryModels(List<UserHistoryModel> userHistoryModels) {
    this.userHistoryModels = userHistoryModels;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserHistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_history,parent,false);
    UserHistoryPopUp = new Dialog(view.getContext());
    UserHistoryPopUp.setContentView(R.layout.user_history_pop_up);
    bookingid_pop_up = UserHistoryPopUp.findViewById(R.id.BookingId);
    check_in_date_time_pop_up = UserHistoryPopUp.findViewById(R.id.check_in_date_time_pop_up);
    room_no = UserHistoryPopUp.findViewById(R.id.Room_no_pop_up);
    floor_no = UserHistoryPopUp.findViewById(R.id.Floor_no_pop_up);
    room_type = UserHistoryPopUp.findViewById(R.id.Room_Type_pop_up);
    close_btn = UserHistoryPopUp.findViewById(R.id.Close_btn);

    return new UserHistoryViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserHistoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final String bookingid = userHistoryModels.get(position).getBookingId();
    final Timestamp check_in_d_t = userHistoryModels.get(position).getCheck_in_date_time();
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
    holder.bookingid.setText(bookingid);
    holder.showdetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bookingid_pop_up.setText(bookingid);
            check_in_date_time_pop_up.setText(sdf.format(check_in_d_t.toDate()));
            room_no.setText(String.valueOf(userHistoryModels.get(position).getRoomNo()));
            floor_no.setText(String.valueOf(userHistoryModels.get(position).getFloorNo()));
            room_type.setText(userHistoryModels.get(position).getRoomType());
            UserHistoryPopUp.show();
            close_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    UserHistoryPopUp.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    if(userHistoryModels==null){
        return 0;
    }
    else {

    return userHistoryModels.size();}
}

public class UserHistoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView bookingid;
    private Button showdetails;


    public UserHistoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        bookingid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Booking_id_textview);
        showdetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Show_booking_details);

    }



}
```

}

Here is my viewmodel class:

```
public class UserHistoryViewModel extends ViewModel implements FirebaseRespositary.OnFirestoreTaskCompleted {
private MutableLiveData<List<UserHistoryModel>> UserHistoryData = new MutableLiveData<List<UserHistoryModel>>();
private MutableLiveData<Integer> size1 = new MutableLiveData<>();




public UserHistoryViewModel(){

}

public LiveData<Integer> getSize1(String emailId) {
    firebaseRespositary.getSize(emailId);
    return size1;
}

public LiveData<List<UserHistoryModel>> getUserHistoryData(String emaild) {
    firebaseRespositary.getData(emaild);
    return UserHistoryData;
}


private FirebaseRespositary firebaseRespositary = new FirebaseRespositary(this);

@Override
public void UserCheckedInDetails(List<UserHistoryModel> userHistoryViewModels) {
        UserHistoryData.setValue(userHistoryViewModels);
}

@Override
public void FirestoreError(Exception e) {

}

@Override
public void UserHistorySize(int size) {
    size1.setValue(size);
}
```

}
Here is my observer:

```
final String currentuser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
   final UserHistoryViewModel userHistoryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(UserHistoryViewModel.class);
    userHistoryViewModel.getSize1(currentuser).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(final Integer integer) {
            if(integer!=0){
                no_data_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                userHistoryViewModel.getUserHistoryData(currentuser).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<UserHistoryModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(List<UserHistoryModel> userHistoryModels) {
                        no_data_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if(integer!=0) {
                            if (userHistoryModels.size() != 0) {
                                no_data_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                no_data.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                check_data.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                userHistoryModelList.addAll(userHistoryModels);
                                userHistoryViewAdapter.setUserHistoryModels(userHistoryModelList);
                                
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
            }else{
                userHistoryModelList.clear();
                userHistoryViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                no_data_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                check_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
```

logout function:

```
    private void Logout() {
        if(network.isConnectingToInternet()){
//            if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
//                ((ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
//                        .clearApplicationUserData();
//                return;
//            }
            no_data_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            userHistoryModelList.clear();
            userHistoryViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            no_data_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Sign out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        firebaseAuth.signOut();

        navController.navigate(R.id.action_mainpage_to_loginscreen);
                }
        else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("No Internet")
                    .setMessage("Please connect to Internet first.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using a ListAdapter<X, Y> or RecyclerView.Adapter implementation?

Comment: I am using RecyclerView.Adapter<UserHistoryViewAdapter.UserHistoryViewHolder>

Comment: Can u tell where recyclerview stores data

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't store data. It manages a set of ViewHolder instances, which are created/updated by your Adapter class.

Comment: check my adapter is properly set

Comment: It looks like you're never clearing your userHistoryModels values. In your observer, if you historyModels list is empty, you don't do anything. So if your logout is clearing your userHistoryModels list, and it pushes onto your LiveData, your `onChanged` method will see it, but the check if size() != 0 will skip any update to your adapter, leaving the previous values in place.

Comment: if (userHistoryModels.size() != 0) {no_data_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    no_data.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    check_data.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    userHistoryModelList.addAll(userHistoryModels);
                                    userHistoryViewAdapter.setUserHistoryModels(userHistoryModelList);
                                    userHistoryViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

Comment: after ur reply i have made changes check it,in  logout function i have clear userhistorymodelist and notifyadapter,but still it shows previous data

Comment: is there any other way we can communicate  as stackoverflow restricts long character i cannot explain

Comment: I have solved that bug but now in recycler view i am getting same data again and again

Comment: None of your snippets show your logout function so I can't really help pinpoint what the issue is. From your snippets it looks like you only update your adapter when your user list has items in it. If your logout function is updating your livedata list to an empty list your observer is currently not going to update your adapter list.

Comment: Check it i have updated whole code

Comment: You are calling clear() on the list held in your fragment but not updating the adapter with that empty list on logout. So the notifyDataSetChange call just rebinds the same list the adapter had before.

Comment: thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `ListAdapter` you can do the following when you want to clear your RecyclerView data:

```
myListAdapter.submitList(emptyList())
```

Java:

```
myListAdapter.submitList(new ArrayList<YourType>());
```

If you are using a `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation, you'll want to reset your adapter's internal data to be empty and then notify the adapter that data has changed.

In your Adapter class:

```
private val _myLocalListOfData = mutableListOf<YourType>()

fun clearData() {
  _myLocalListOfData.clear()
  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Java Version:

```
private List<YourType> _myLocalListOfData = new ArrayList<YourType>();

public void clearData() {
  _myLocalListOfData.clear();
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: can u write code in java as i am not familer with kotlin

Comment: @ShreySoni I took a shot. I think the Java syntax is correct, but it's been a while.

Comment: I have used ur code and getting error list cannot cast to model

Comment: u can check @taki eddine reply were i have edit his post ,i have paste my code and erroe is comming in userHistoryList.add(userhistorymodel)

Comment: In my code I used `YourType` for the type argument in the list. Make sure you change that to whatever your object type is. Looks like it should be `UserHistoryModel`

Comment: i have changed type with this private List<UserHistoryModel> userHistoryModelList = new ArrayList<UserHistoryModel>();

Comment: and after onchange i have add userHistoryModelList.add(userHistoryModel) ,,here it says  require type userhistorymodel but i am giving list.

Comment: I think we're a little off base from the original problem here, but I think you need to call `addAll` if you are trying to append a list to an existing list. `add` will append a single item, `addAll` will append another List of items

Comment: addall worked for me and in logout i have clear list and notfyadapter ,but when i login in again with different account i can still see previous login details

Comment: It sounds like 1 of 2 things is occurring: Your Adapter is not properly clearing its data list, or your code that is getting your list to supply to your adapter is returning the wrong data.

Comment: If you're using my snippet above in your adapter, make sure you are referencing the `_myLocalListOfData` when building your ViewHolders. If you were already maintaining a list of data in your Adapater, just get rid of `_myLocalListOfData` and clear your existing list on `clearData()`

Comment: check my adapter is properly set

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an arraylist or Mutablelist in your activity , when the user clicks log out call clear() on the list and notify the adapter